# Error xhr.abort() is not a function using Ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

Im trying to abort an Ajax request using `.abort()` method. But it keeps throwing the error

```
xhr.abort is not a function
```

This is the hook where Im calling it:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const xhr = $.ajax(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`)
      .then(sleeper(1)) // Create some latency
      .then(response => {
        setPokemon(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    return () => {
      xhr.abort(); // ERROR: xhr.abort is not a function
    };
  }, [name]);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-currying-hozqo?file=/src/App.js:338-658)

jQuery version: 3.4.1

Comment: Did you mean `.fail()`? Abort is not a jqXHR method. See More: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: It's related to Version 3 of jQuery: https://www.wikitechy.com/tutorials/javascript/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery

Comment: @Twisty Solved, thanks!

Comment: Great! It might be helpful to post your own solution for others to see.

Answer (score 2):

As @Twisty said at comments, its related to the version of jQuery. For version 3, we need to pass an instance of `XMLHttpRequest`:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest(); // Create a XMLHttpRequest instance
    $.ajax({
      url: `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`,
      xhr: function() { // return the instance here
        return xhr;
      }
    })
      .then(sleeper(1))
      .then(response => {
        setPokemon(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    return () => {
      xhr.abort(); // Succesfully aborted on React unmount lifecycle
    };
  }, [name]);
```

[Fixed demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-feather-m6rfk?file=/src/App.js:338-784)